# QGIS Zanzibar how to crop?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, clip

I have georeferenced an old OS map and I have now imported the OS data shapefile for boundaries for England. How can I get rid of the extra data that extends beyond my map and just leave my scanned map with the boundary layer?

This is a screenshot of what it looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Using the `Vector Overlay->Extract/clip by extent` tool in the processing toolbox will produce almost what you want:

[image]

But as you can see you get the bounding box not the actual boundary of the raster. I had hoped you could use the `Vector geometry->Minimum bounding geometry` but that only works on vector layers.

So if you must have the exact matching boundary you will need to create a temporary memory polygon layer and [add the bounding polygon by hand](https://geo.nls.uk/urbhist/guides_vectorlayerqgis.html) and use that in the clip operation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ian I will try that - but can you also explain what a "scratch polygon layer" and what you mean by adding "the bounding polygon by hand"? I know this is probably a dumb question, but why isn't there simply a cropping tool as per photoshop? (I assume that "clip" is a QGIS/GIS term for crop?) Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot clip a vector layer with a raster layer, so do the following

1. Use Processing Toolbox > Layer Tools > Extract layer extent for the scanned map layer.
2. Now you can use Processing Toolbox > Vector overlay > Clip and choose the OS data shapefile as Input layer and the extent layer generated in Step 1 as the Overlay layer.

Comment: Hi I did as you suggested re 1 above and used processing toolbox>layer tools>Extract Layer extent on the scanned map and get this error message  "files are not supported by this algorithm" Not sure how to proceed. It feels as if this should be such a routine and easy thing to accomplish as per crop in photoshop. Any thoughts please?

Comment: It is a pretty routine thing to do. Not sure why the error. Is your scanned map georeferenced? Possible to post a link to the source data?

Comment: Yes. I have three layers. 1 Streetviewmap, 2 scanned georef map and 3 Shapefile of boundaries. The source data for boundaries is UK Ordnance Survey shape files. It that the source file you meant as above?

Comment: The streetview map is from a web service? If so, you can't clip those and probably explains the error. If you really want to hide the web layer, only way is to mask it. Try the 'mask' plugin

Comment: Hi. I’m just trying to clip my map. So I put the input as raster (my scanned georef map) and the mask is the shapefile parish boundary. Don’t intend crop streetviewmap as that was just for georef. Does that mean if I want clip need to delete streetviewmap layer?

Comment: No if you are not using the streetview layer in clipping, it doesn't matter. See the other answer which has a detailed answer. If you are not able to make it work too, best option is to share your data so we can help you further.

Comment: When you say share my data do you mean the map I am trying to clip and the shapefile - if so how do I do that please?

Comment: ya, zip the raster and shapefiles and upload them to dropbox/drive and post a link.

Comment: You make it sound very easy. Can I zip direct from the project or do I zip the two files from my folders. This must sound dumb to you but I’m using QGIS to research historical geography rather than the converse. I’m not as IT savvy as you I fear.